# Running a loop and executing a function after each iteration of loop: r

Tags: r, loops

I'm running a google big query script off of RStudio.

I have one important parameterised variable. Which needs to be replaced with values in a dataframe

```
health_tags<-read.csv('marker_tags.csv')
health_tags<-tail(tags, 7)
```

I have built a function which executes my query whilst adding the parameters to my variables.

```
query_details (MD2_date_start="2018-06-06",    
               MD2_date_end="2018-07-07",
               Sterile_tag="7894")
```

So "query_details" is a function API call which fills in details for BQ to run. How do I write a looper which replaces the values in "sterile_tag" with the codes found in the health_tags CSV and then run the "query_details" function each time until all iterations have completed.

Comment: could you show the `str` of `health_tags`? I want to know what is its type. And, what does `query_details` return ? Does it return anything or just prints the results?

Comment: Health_Tags is a CSV with one column with numbers like this                                 1234                                                                                                                          23232                                                                                                                              847483                                                                                                                       query results sends an API call to execute a query in Google Big Query. So it doesnt return anything human readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sapply` where `column` should be the real name of your column:

```
sapply(health_tags$column, function(x) query_details (MD2_date_start="2018-06-06",    
                                                      MD2_date_end="2018-07-07",
                                                      Sterile_tag=as.character(x)))
```

Comment: hmm I get this error "Error during wrapup: Bad Request (HTTP 400)."

Comment: that's how the loop can be, `Sterile_tag` accept integer value or something else?

Comment: AHHH you genius YOLO!! it takes the numbers as a string not an integer!!

Comment: hmm I cant seem to turn them into strings